# Java socket: null

Tags: java, android, tcp

I'm trying to connect a to a TCP server with an Android client. But when I try to connect (in debug) I always get the message that the socket is null.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
boolean connection = false;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
Socket client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try
    {
        client = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", xx);
        connection=true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        listItem.add("Could not connect");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Socket(host, port); make sure you follow this rule.

Comment: Try creating your socket on a background thread. You're likely falling foul of UI network exceptions.

Comment: Stack trace please.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw Follow what rule?

Comment: @EJP that you're passing the correct host name and port number as arguments.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw So why not say so in the first place? Your initial comment is meaningless. In any case his problem isn't a `ConnectException`, or so he says, which is what would happen if his host or port weren't correct.